# How to know which column or property is causing an EF "The specified cast is not valid" error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework to execute some queries like this:

```
List<Entity> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>(query).ToList()
```

And I'm having the typical cast error in Entity Framework which says:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'Sometype' type to the
>   'Anothertype' type is not valid

This is because I have made a lot of changes in the database and I was expecting something like this. Some properties in the Entity class have different type that the columns in the database (some strings are decimals and so on).

However, I would like to know which columns or properties are not casting well, but I can't find any useful information in the exception.

Is there any way to know this?

Comment: Please be more specific about your table schema and EF objects. Also, if you're using database first just recreate the EF model from the DB. I'm going to have to say just go property by property to make sure... as painful as it sounds.  In my experience, nullable vs non-nullable properties give simple issues to fix for this.

Comment: The schema is not important for the question, actually. I mean, it will not depend on how is my database, I just want to know if it's possible to know  which columns are causing the problem without re-check all my entities.